# How to set a trigger which update a field after insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table called list which has a id,name and size. Size stores the length of the name field. I want to update this field after insertion. In other words, Trigger after insert ( yes I can do in the code but I just curios about it) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a BEFORE INSERT trigger. Use the keyword *new* to refer to the columns about to be inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT
ON list FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.size = LENGTH(NEW.name)
```